# Why isn't the 'Message Seller' button in my React component navigating to the desired page?

Tags: reactjs, button, jsx, react-navigation, router

I'm working on a React application.
I have a `PostFooter` component responsible for displaying various functionalities related to a post, such as liking the post, commenting on it, and messaging the seller.
I'm encountering an issue with the `handleButtonClick` function, which is intended to navigate to another page (`ChatPage`) when the "Message Seller" button is clicked.

The handleButtonClick function inside my PostFooter component is not navigating to the desired page (`./pages/ChatPage/ChatPage`) when the "Message Seller" button is clicked. How can I properly implement the navigation functionality in this scenario?

here is some of my code

```
import { Box, Button, Flex, Input, InputGroup, InputRightElement, Text, useDisclosure } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { CommentLogo, NotificationsLogo, UnlikeLogo } from "../../assets/constants";
import usePostComment from "../../hooks/usePostComment";
import useAuthStore from "../../store/authStore";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import useLikePost from "../../hooks/useLikePost";
import { timeAgo } from "../../utils/timeAgo";
import CommentsModal from "../Modals/CommentsModal";

const PostFooter = ({ post, isProfilePage, creatorProfile }) => {
    const { isCommenting, handlePostComment } = usePostComment();
    const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
    const [caption, setCaption] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("");
    const [selectedCondition, setSelectedCondition] = useState("");
    const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
    const authUser = useAuthStore((state) => state.user);
    const commentRef = useRef(null);
    const { handleLikePost, isLiked, likes } = useLikePost(post);
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

    const handleSubmitComment = async () => {
        await handlePostComment(post.id, comment);
        setComment("");
    };

    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        const navigate = useNavigate;
        // Navigate to another page when the button is clicked
        navigate("./pages/ChatPage/ChatPage");
    };

    return (
        <Box mb={10} marginTop={"auto"}>
            <Flex alignItems={"center"} gap={4} w={"full"} pt={0} mb={2} mt={4}>
                <Box onClick={handleLikePost} cursor={"pointer"} fontSize={18}>
                    {!isLiked ? <NotificationsLogo /> : <UnlikeLogo />}
                </Box>
                <Box cursor={"pointer"} fontSize={18} onClick={() => commentRef.current.focus()}>
                    <CommentLogo />
                </Box>
                <Box>
                    <Button fontSize={18} colorScheme="blue" onClick={handleButtonClick}>Message Seller</Button>
                </Box>
            </Flex>
            <Text fontWeight={600} fontSize={"sm"}>
                {likes} likes
            </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

The react-router-dom useNavigate hook needs to be called as a function to get the navigation function, but in your code, you are missing the parentheses. It should be like this:

```
       const handleButtonClick = () => {
        const navigate = useNavigate();
        navigate("./pages/ChatPage/ChatPage");
    };
```

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

The `useNavigate` hook should be outside the function:
e.g. `const navigate = useNavigate();`

```js
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmitComment = async () => {
        await handlePostComment(post.id, comment);
        setComment("");
    };
    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        navigate("/Chat");
    };
```